# SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a SQL question. The following piece of SQL code gives a "SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'." Why does this error occure?

```
INSERT INTO [Layer](ComponentNumber) 
OUTPUT inserted.ComponentNumber
VALUES (:component_number)
WHERE LayerID = :layer_id
```

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server; (2) Why do you have an `OUTPUT` clause for a column where you are passing in the value.  You know the value; it is a parameter.

Comment: Did you try `WHERE LayderID = layer_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want an `update`:

```
UPDATE [Layer]
    SET ComponentNumber = :component_number
    OUTPUT inserted.ComponentNumber
    WHERE LayerID = :layer_id;
```

It is unclear why you would use an `OUTPUT` clause for this.  You are passing in the value for `ComponentNumber`.

Comment: Your code works perfect. Thank you for your explanation Gordon! The OUTPUT is indeed not necessary.

Comment: I used the OUTPUT to see whether the value has been inserted in ComponentNumber. So the OUTPUT shows that the value has been inserted, but the value does not change in the database. Could this be due to column rights that are read only? If so how do you change column rights to read&write?

Comment: @Vivaldab . .  . You should ask a *new* question and provide a db<>fiddle to illustrate what you mean by "the value does not change in the database".  If any rows match the `where` conditions, then the rows should be updated.